# Is this upscaling algorithm in place already?

Tags: production, video-production

Okay, so my question is, if you were to double the amount of pixels, and the resolution, wouldn't that be the perfect solution to upscaling? Or would that cause problems, but considering it would just be duplicating the amount of pixels instead of stretching them out, would there be possible issues with that? Or does that technology not exist yet? Or better yet would it be pointless?

Thanks for your answers! :)

Example: (I'm not a drawer)

[image]

Comment: What Program are you using?

Comment: Piskel (Just for the example)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to answer this is to look through the wiki on comparison on image scaling algorithms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_gallery_of_image_scaling_algorithms Might provide some insight if you go through and read each of the interpolation types. If you look at neighbor specifically it should answer alot of your questions. I found it quite helpful as you can see what the difference between the various options on the market is visually.

In terms of pixel art I believe there is a scaling algorithm that does what you show in your picture, just this doesn't 'holdup' when dealing with more complex pixel displays...again look at how lousy neighbour is in comparison to the other upscalers.